# Error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN de manera intermitente

Tags: dns, redes, dominio

Tengo un sitio web (gymmyadmin.com) para uso interno de la empresa y que usamos desde varias ubicaciones. De manera intermitente en 1-2 sucursales (distintas ubicaciones) el sitio se cae con un error **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN**.
En estas máquinas el internet está bien pues navegas en otros sitios, pero nuestro sitio muestra este error.

No es un problema de caché, pues aunque abras otro navegador que nunca has usado, sale el mismo error. Ya hicimos release de la IP, renew, flushdns, etc; desactivo antivirus, firewall, y nada. Si conectas esa máquina a otra red (ejemplo, compartiendo el internet de tu celular), el sitio se muestra correctamente.

Lo raro es que a la mañana siguiente todo vuelve a la normalidad y el problema regresa en otra sucursal 10-15 días después.
Esto ya me tiene loco, pues nada de lo que veo en internet me ha funcionado.
Sucede con diferentes proveedores de internet, con diferentes rangos de IP, en diferentes ciudades, sin un patrón específico.
El proveedor de internet dice que no es problema de ellos, pues hay internet... y el proveedor de hosting y dominio que tampoco es problema de ellos, pues la página abre en las pruebas que ellos han hecho.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿También llegó a pasarte que si logra resolver la dirección, la carga del sitio era lenta? ¿O cuando logra cargar lo hace rápidamente?

Comment: No, no logro que cargue... se mantiene ese DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN haga lo que haga, en este mismo instante tengo el problema en 4 de las 9 sucursales. Normalmente al día siguiente todo está bien, pero ya hoy es el segundo día y el problema se mantiene.

Comment: Esto es un problema de enrutado, verifica que toda la empresa este detrás del mismo DNS privado y que en algún lugar de tu red donde está la regla de enrutamiento todos los equipo estén bajo esa misma red... de lo contrario ocurrirá esto al intentar resolver una URL en Internet que no existe... otra forma de manejarlo es colocando en el archivo C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts al final algo como XXX.XXX.XXX gymmyadmin.com otra cosa que te recomiendo es no usar .com usa una TLD propio.

Comment: recomendare el cierre de la pregunta por que tiene que ver con temas que no son de programacion. incluso creo que en este otro sitio seria mejor recibida: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si a alguien le sucediera lo mismo, resolví el problema cambiando los DNS en windows y poniendo los DNS de google, en las propiedades de TCP/IPv4 y TCP/IPv6, tal cual explican en el siguiente enlace:
https://mentecuriosa.net/como-poner-los-dns-de-google-en-la-pc/